# In Safari, repeat setAttributeNS() calls create additional attributes

Tags: javascript, svg, safari

In Chrome and FF, if I run this line

```
SOME_SVG_NODE.setAttributeNS("http://example.com","ex:attr",1)
```

then this line later:

```
SOME_SVG_NODE.setAttributeNS("http://example.com","ex:attr",2)
```

The result is: `<node ex:attr="2">...`

In Safari, the result is: `<node ex:attr="1" attr"2">...`

In Safari, if I run the two lines immediately after one another, the result matches Chrome and FF...

Am I missing something or doing something irregular? Is there some reason a successive call to setAttributeNS is ambiguous such that different browsers interpret it differently?

**Full Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g></g>
 </svg>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  let g = document.querySelector("g")
  g.setAttributeNS("http://example.com","ex:attr","1")
  g.setAttributeNS("http://example.com","ex:attr","2")
  console.log(g)

  document.addEventListener("mousedown",e=>{
   g.setAttributeNS("http://example.com","ex:attr","3")
   console.log(g)
  })
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the name space url "http://example.com"? should it be: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"? can you run same example with proper NS and then see if the issue is still there?

Comment: Afraid I don't follow. As far as I understand this entry (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS) the namespace value can be whatever you'd like — the purpose being to provide a unique scope for the attribute name in argument 2. Are there limitations to what can be used in the namespace argument for setAttributeNS ?

Comment: Moreover, it's my understanding that the svg namespace is for svg attributes, and when defining svg attributes via setAttributeNS, you're supposed to set the namespace argument to null, e.g. `setAttributeNS("http://w3.org/2000/svg","transform",...)` should be `setAttributeNS(null,"transform",...)`, so I'm not sure why you'd ever use the actual svg namespace with setAttributeNS.

Comment: makes sense;) sorry I was just learning that myself. And yes you are right it does not matter also in this issue case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in Safari’s inspector.
There is only one attribute tracked under the hood.
The issue has been reported and a fix is incoming.